# cURL takes long time to start download

Tags: php, curl, download, downloading-website-files

I'am trying to download a file (1GB) on server C via server B, which has the code:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=How to Use Git and GitHub Videos.zip");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

$url = "http://zips.udacity-data.com/ud775/How%20to%20Use%20Git%20and%20GitHub%20Videos.zip";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 256);

curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I was expecting it will momentally start dwonlaoding a file. But instead I have to wait so long time till my browser window will ask where to save it. I thought `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 256);` means that it will transfer the file chunk by chunk so i don'thave to wait it will read the all file first.

So why it takes so long time to start download? How can I fix it? if  this method is wrong please suggest me something else

Answer (score 1):

That's because `curl_exec()` blocks till it reads full response (consuming 1GB of memory in the process in your case). You can make it call your own function however:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function($ch, $buffer) {
  echo $buffer;
  return strlen($buffer);
});
curl_exec ($ch); // curl will call CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION as it receives data inside curl_exec()
```

Be sure `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is not set at all, neither to false, neither to true.

Comment: thank you for reply sir, I spent 5 hours trying to solve this task, sir please can you write here the working solution. I don't know where to paste your code and where to remove `curl_exec()`. Please sir

Comment: Marek, thank you for response, but it didn't help. It still waits to read all file to memory. Please take a look at this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563782/php-curl-start-giving-data-to-browser-withut-waiting-to-read-all)