# php & cURL start giving data to browser withut waiting to read all?

Tags: php, curl, download, downloading-website-files

Hi i'm trying to downlaod a file in my browser via proxy script on my web server. The code on webserver is:

```
<?php
$file = 'http://example.com/somefile.mp3';
download($file,2000);

/*
Set Headers
Get total size of file
Then loop through the total size incrementing a chunck size
*/
function download($file,$chunks){
    set_time_limit(0);
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    $size = get_size($file);
    header('Content-Length: '.$size);

    $i = 0;
    while($i<=$size){
        //Output the chunk
        get_chunk($file,(($i==0)?$i:$i+1),((($i+$chunks)>$size)?$size:$i+$chunks));
        $i = ($i+$chunks);
    }

}

//Callback function for CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, This is what prints the chunk
function chunk($ch, $str) {
    print($str);
    return strlen($str);
}

//Function to get a range of bytes from the remote file
function get_chunk($file,$start,$end){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE, $start.'-'.$end);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'chunk');
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}

//Get total size of file
function get_size($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
    return intval($size);
}
?>
```

When i try to download a big file (more than 500mb fo example) it waits too long time (someimtes throws 500 error of memory limit), and then after few minutes my browser asks where to save it and starts downloading.

What should I do to start downloading in browser immediatly as cURL gets first chunk of a file??? also I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560855/curl-takes-long-time-to-start-download/30561050#30561050) but the asnswer didn't help. It still loads all to memory first and then gives to browser.

**Dear community I'm stucked at it for 2 days. PLEASE HELP!!!**

Comment: Try putting `readfile($file)` at the end of your download function

Comment: `readfile()` load first to memeory and then lets to download it, so there in no point to use it!